# How to call another class with button and pass variable between classes?

Tags: python, class, wxpython, share

I want to pass variable between GUI classes. Below, when i Show **Other_b  class**, it Show frame but i couldn't get **Main1 class**' data to there. However when i try to Show **Other_a class**, it passes **x** value (because of it is inside of **__init__**) but it doesn't pass the **y** value because of it is related to **Btn2**(and of course because of not having any frame to pressing button).

How can i overcome this problem? Any help would be appreciated.

```
import wx

class Main1 (wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent )
        self.bSizer1 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )
        self.Btn1 = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Btn1", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.bSizer1.Add( self.Btn1, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )
        self.SetSizer( self.bSizer1 )
        self.Btn1.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.btn1_f )


    def btn1_f( self, event ):
        print("here 1")
        self.x = 12
        self.y = 30

        a=Other_a(self).Show()
        b=Other_b(self).Show()


class Other_a (wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, foo):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self )
        self.bSizer2 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )
        self.Btn2 = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Btn 2", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.bSizer2.Add( self.Btn2, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )
        self.SetSizer( self.bSizer2 )
        self.Btn2.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.btn2_f )

        print("here 2")
        print(foo.x)

    def btn2_f(self,foo):
        print("here 3")
        print(foo.y)

class Other_b (wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent )
        self.bSizer3 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )
        self.Btn3 = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Btn 2", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.bSizer3.Add( self.Btn3, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )
        self.SetSizer( self.bSizer3 )
        self.Btn3.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.btn3_f )
        print("here 4")

    def btn3_f(self,event):
        print("here 5")
        print(self.x)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = Main1(None)
    frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close!
A few judicious uses of `self` and `parent` resolve your issues.

```
import wx

class Main1 (wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent )
        self.bSizer1 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )
        self.Btn1 = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Btn1", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.bSizer1.Add( self.Btn1, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )
        self.SetSizer( self.bSizer1 )
        self.Btn1.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.btn1_f )


    def btn1_f( self, event ):
        print("here 1")
        self.x = 12
        self.y = 30

        a=Other_a(parent=self).Show()
        b=Other_b(parent=self).Show()


class Other_a (wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__ (self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.bSizer2 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )
        self.Btn2 = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Btn A 2", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.bSizer2.Add( self.Btn2, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )
        self.SetSizer( self.bSizer2 )
        self.Btn2.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.btn2_f )

        print("here 2")
        print(self.parent.x)

    def btn2_f(self,foo):
        print("here 3")
        print(self.parent.y)

class Other_b (wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent )
        self.parent = parent
        self.bSizer3 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )
        self.Btn3 = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Btn B 2", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.bSizer3.Add( self.Btn3, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )
        self.SetSizer( self.bSizer3 )
        self.Btn3.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.btn3_f )
        print("here 4")

    def btn3_f(self,event):
        print("here 5")
        print(self.parent.x)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = Main1(None)
    frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Gives:

```
python 20190529.py
here 1
here 2
12
here 4
here 3
30
here 5
12
```

Here is the `diff` between your code and the code above:

```
<         a=Other_a(self).Show()
<         b=Other_b(self).Show()
---
>         a=Other_a(parent=self).Show()
>         b=Other_b(parent=self).Show()
23,24c23,25
<     def __init__(self, foo):
<         wx.Frame.__init__ ( self )
---
>     def __init__(self, parent):
>         wx.Frame.__init__ (self,parent)
>         self.parent = parent
26c27
<         self.Btn2 = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Btn 2", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
---
>         self.Btn2 = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Btn A 2", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
32c33
<         print(foo.x)
---
>         print(self.parent.x)
36c37
<         print(foo.y)
---
>         print(self.parent.y)
40a42
>         self.parent = parent
42c44
<         self.Btn3 = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Btn 2", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
---
>         self.Btn3 = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Btn B 2", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
50c52
<         print(self.x)
---
>         print(self.parent.x)
```

Answer (score 2):

I arrange your code a little bit so now it passes the variable from the Main1 class to the Other classes.

The main problem is that you are not passing the variables at all. The line `a=Other_a(self).Show()` in your code is actually giving the entire `frame` to the `Other_a` class. If you want to pass the `x` and `y` values then you can give a list `[self.x, self.y]` as the `foo` value for `Other_a`.

Then, in the instance `a` of the class `Other_a` you need a line like `self.foo = foo`. Why? Because you want to use the value of `foo` outside of the `__init__` method.

The same happens with `b` and `Other_b`.

Take a look [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) for more details about how clasess work in Python.

```
import wx

class Main1(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.bSizer1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.Btn1 = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Btn1", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        self.bSizer1.Add(self.Btn1, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.SetSizer(self.bSizer1)
        self.Btn1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.btn1_f)


    def btn1_f(self, event):
        print("here 1")
        self.x = 12
        self.y = 30

        a = Other_a([self.x, self.y])
        a.Show()
        b = Other_b(self.x)
        b.Show()


class Other_a(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        self.bSizer2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.Btn2 = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Btn 2a", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        self.bSizer2.Add(self.Btn2, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.SetSizer(self.bSizer2)
        self.Btn2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.btn2_f)

        print("here 2")
        print(self.foo[0])

    def btn2_f(self, event):
        print("here 3")
        print(self.foo[1])

class Other_b(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        self.bSizer3 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.Btn3 = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Btn 2b", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        self.bSizer3.Add(self.Btn3, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.SetSizer(self.bSizer3)
        self.Btn3.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.btn3_f)
        print("here 4")

    def btn3_f(self, event):
        print("here 5")
        print(self.x)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = Main1(None)
    frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I wish i could accept this answer too.  I gave priority to time. Thank you so much, it Works too.

Comment: Doesn't stop me upvoting though :)